CPVC versus cast metal tub spout?
I want to replace the cheap, flimsy, and boring spout on my tub with a nicer one that seems to be cast metal (to wit, it has some heft to it). Unfortunately, whatever cheapskate built my house used CPVC everywhere, even for the tub stub-out.
Now... the bottom of the pipe does appear to be firmly resting on the tile where it comes through the wall, so there is a point of leverage there rather than the spout's entire weight hanging off the down-pipe from the valve. Even so... how concerned should I be about just installing the spout on the CPVC as-is? Is there some way of reinforcing things so the pipe isn't taking the full weight?
(I realize replacing the pipe would be ideal, but I really, really don't want to have to rip up tile and drywall. And the relevant wall sticks out into the bathroom with the vanity on the other side, so trying to come in from the back would likely be more work than coming in from the front.)

Unless you plan on sitting on the spout, or it is cast iron and lead,  attaching it to the cpvc should be fine.
I think if you tried to break the cpvc you would be surprised how hard it is.
If the issue is that the cpvc is floppy in the wall, then edit the question, because that is a different issue.

I'm mostly concerned about fatigue-over-time, as I've seen some competing claims that this is a problem. OTOH, it might not be my problem...

I've been rehabbing and remodeling home for over50 years. Never fount weight of a tub spout on cpvc to cause a problem.
